# DataSet not being filled and I can not understand why...?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, dataset, gridview-sorting

So I am having an issue with a project I am working on. I am creating a gridview that will have the paging and sorting handled by the SQL Server due to large amounts of data in our queries. I have downloaded an example oof how to do this, changes the sample SQL to fit my tables and it tests just fine. Once I transfer this code to my main project the dataset is not being filled with any of the data. I know for fact the code works, I know the SQL returns 48 rows and should be paged at 25 rows per page. I have even tried running the SQL in an function that returns an ArrayList then converting that into a Data Table and filling the DataSet, the Data Tables are being filled but the data count on the DataSet comes back as 0.... I am at a total loss. I am getting no errors at all, and it is communicating with my DataBase. Any help would be great as I am beyond at a loss on this one.

Here is my code for filling the DataSet;

```
public DataSet GetDataSet(string sql) {
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        conn.Open();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    } 

    return ds;
}
```

I have also tried this code;

```
   SqlConnection src = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);

        try
        {
            src.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, src))
            {

                DataTable report = new DataTable();
                DA.Fill(report);
                DS = new DataSet();
                DS.Tables.Add(report);

            }


            src.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. It might be something to do with query passed to GetDataSet method.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I am not very versed in DataSets sadly. I know the query works fine, right now for testing and to start it just a SELECT * FROM tbCompany to generate a list of our clients.

Answer (score 0):

in the first code, fill the ds with table first like this

```
con.open();
adapter.Fill(ds,"THE TABLE NAME EXACTLY IN  YOUR DB");
GridView1.DataSource= ds.Tables["THE TABLE NAME EXACTLY IN  YOUR DB"];
GridView1.DataBind();
```